# How to restore packages removed by installing a program

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, apt

I was trying to install the normal map plugin for gimp, and I tried installing the package gimp-normalmap:i386 from the Software Manager on Linux Mint.  As I was installing it, I realized that it was removing a number of important packages.  One of my video editors, gimp, several python packages, and the cinnamon desktop environment.  I closed out of the Software Manager as fast as I could (because there wasn't an abort button), but it had already removed most of those packages.  It turns out that the package I was originally looking for was gimp-normalmap.  Now I can't adjust anything that has to do with my desktop environment and all the settings are missing.  What is the best way to restore all the packages removed by this software?  Also, cinnamon is offered as a package in the Software Manager.  Is it safe to install this?  Preferably, I would also like to get back all the python files it removed, and I can't figure out which ones it did even if I go back to the package in the software manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can check what has been installed or uninstalled etc via the aptitude logs. You will need to be root or use sudo to view the log files.

You can check the logs using this command:

```
sudo cat /var/log/apt/term.log
```

For long log files u can pipe to more like this:

```
sudo cat /var/log/apt/term.log | more
```

Then you can use space bar to page down, enter to go down 1 line at a time, and q to quit. There's lots more u can do via "more". To learn more try and man, like this:

```
man more
```

You should be able to see what was uninstalled/removed. That way you can reinstall what you think you may need. Or just reinstall everything before you made that last change.

If its been a while older logs are gzip'ed so u can go back in history as well. You will need to extract those before you can read them via cat or a text editor.

Once you determine what was uninstalled you can reinstall them by using:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall package1 package2
```

package1 being one of the packages you saw in the log file, just list them all out using spaces between each one to install multiple packages at once.

Comment: Awesome! I think I've reinstalled most of the removed packages, but this looks like a promising method. I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: When I try to run the first command by sudo /var/log/apt/term.log, it says that the command is not found, but when I run it without the sudo in front of it, it says "Permission denied".  How can I fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: try this: sudo cat /var/log/apt/term.log
also if its a long log u can use: sudo cat /var/log/apt/term.log | more
then you can use space bar for page down, enter to go down a line, and q to quit. I added that to my original post for you.

Comment: I think it worked, but for some reason the logs didn't say anything about the programs that I'm certain it removed.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice, this is way better than my answer, didn't know apt kept it's own log. Guess you learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling ubuntu-desktop as per [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1695721)

Run these commands in order:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f  
sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Edit: I also recommend creating a dump of your package list next time you uninstall a lot of packages at once, just in case anything goes wrong you can restore them. See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37700/dump-dpkg-package-list-for-fresh-installation)

Comment: Will that completely reinstall my operating system?

Comment: It will just reinstall packages related to Ubuntu's unity desktop environment. It will at least get your system back in working order. Mint/Ubuntu/KDE/Gnome are all debian derivatives so any one or all of them can work simultaneously on the same system. You would need to install python and the other libs you require again. Run `apt-get install build-essential` just to make sure all the build libs are still there.

Comment: Okay, but do I need the packages for Unitiy's desktop environment if I'm using Linux Mint's Cinnamon environment?  Thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily, I just assumed you uninstalled cinnamon as this happened to me before when I installed/uninstalled Mint on top of Ubuntu "just to try it out". You can use `sudo apt-get install cinnamon` if you prefer.